# Pyswams Library - how to use my own objective function

Tags: python

Hello I'm trying to use this library: pyswarms and it works fine with the base code that they give

However I'm trying to implement my own objective function and can't quite understand how to do that

This is the code I've got so far:

```
import pyswarms as ps
from pyswarms.utils.functions import single_obj as fx
def f(x): 
    return x**2

options = {'c1':0.5, 'c2': 0.3, 'w':0.9}

optimizer = ps.single.GlobalBestPSO(n_particles=100, dimensions=2, options=options) 

best_cost, best_pos = optimizer.optimize(f, iters=100)

print(best_pos)

print(best_cost)
```

But I get this errors:

```
2023-11-29 15:47:19,748 - pyswarms.single.global_best - INFO - Optimize for 100 iters with {'c1': 0.5, 'c2': 0.3, 'w': 0.9}
pyswarms.single.global_best: 0%| |0/100 Traceback (most recent call last): File/home/ricardo/Documents/Tese/DroneSearchSimulation/temp.py", line 11, in <module> best_cost, best_pos = optimizer.optimize(f, iters=100) File "/home/ricardo/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyswarms/single/global_best.py", line 210, in optimize self.swarm.pbest_pos, self.swarm.pbest_cost = compute_pbest(self.swarm) File "/home/ricardo/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyswarms/backend/operators.py", line 66, in compute_pbest mask_cost = swarm.current_cost < swarm.pbest_cost ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (100,2) (100,)
```

Could anyone help me better understand the library?